# How to get the device details when user uninstalls the ios application

Tags: ios, swift, uninstallation

I am developing an iOS Inhouse application where I need to collect the device details when a user uninstalls the application. Is there any way to achieve this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get the details from where? From the app being uninstalled?

Comment: @maddy: user device details like device id etc..

Comment: Application itself does not receive any signals when being uninstalled. You could collect device details (with timestamp & unique id) each time the app is launched. This way you could at least know when your app was last used on a certain device.

Comment: @rokjarc: The purpose of this is, I want track the users who uninstalls my application.

Comment: @Harsha87 You misunderstood my question. I'm asking what app is to collect the details that you want? It can't be the app being uninstalled. Nothing in iOS tracks such info. The deleted app will be gone (not that it knows who deleted it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you need details like usernames and passwords, credit card information, and Wi-Fi network information then store it in **iCloud Keychain**
https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204085

Comment: what if the device does not have icloud keychain enabled?