# When App deletes (uninstall) getting a mail iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made uninstall some apps from my iOS device. Then i got a mail from app developer for particular app.

How they get particular device make uninstall the app?

I followed below links but not getting proper solution.

1. [Detect iOS application about to delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911361/detect-ios-application-about-to-delete)
2. [How to get the device details when user uninstalls the ios application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092691/how-to-get-the-device-details-when-user-uninstalls-the-ios-application)

Comment: What is reason for down voter?
Can you explain me?

Comment: did you add push notification by using that you can detect

Comment: That's not a programming question to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basically, As you know there is no event is fired when App is deleted from the iPhone.**

But you can do your tasks when the app installs so basically you can check application by sending the [silent push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323903/silent-push-notification-payload).

Apple server will [inform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592576/how-to-detect-user-uninstalled-ios-app-i-need-push-serious-notification-i-don) you when you try to push to an uninstalled instance the notification response at the sender side will **come 410** means, user, no longer activate.

[APNS REQUEST/RESPONSE](http://odecee.com.au/wwdc-2015-big-changes-to-apple-push-notifications/)

If you do not get the proper response from application side that means your application is uninstalled and **you can send the mail**.

Helpful links:

[Call status change web-service when my App is deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412785/call-status-change-web-service-when-my-app-is-deleted)

Comment: If user is not using the app and only remain in device, in this case i have to send silent notification on daily basis. It can be very lengthy and expensive process.

Comment: You have to work with background task, I mentioned the link above.

Comment: Yes, i checked the given link. In this link all about push notification. If i have million of installation of my app. At that time i have to send silent push notification for each million device on daily basis. Now, you can think it is a proper way?

Comment: Basically, You have only one way to do that, also you can filter only those application ex:- who do not hit any web service from last 24-hour.
Also, there is no problem because you can measure that WhatsApp sends num of notification to each user and they have 700 million users in world wide.

Comment: sorry to say that, it is not a proper way. Because it can be possible that many apps we are not using daily basis. so don't required to call a webservice. And some strange thing can be possible is that if user is not used my app from last week or month. and i will sent a mail that "you are uninstalled my app". Is this correct way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151675/discussion-between-nilay-shah-and-salman-ghumsani).